# Why a custom module is not imported however PYTHONPATH and PATH variables are set?

Tags: python, windows, import, path

Working on Windows.
I need to import custom Python module `custom_module`. This custom module imports others custom modules.

The importing works fine when I open a terminal, launch a `.bat` script where I set the systems PATH and PYTHONPATH variables...

```
set PATH=C:/path/to/custmod2;C:/path/to/custmod3;C:/path/to/custmod4;
set PYTHONPATH=C:/path/to/custom_module
```

...then launch such Python script:

```
import custom_module
print("It works")
```

But I would like to set the PATH and PYTHONPATH system variables inside the Python's script.
However, when I modify the script in such manner:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:/path/to/custmod2;C:/path/to/custmod3;C:/path/to/custmod4;"
sys.path.append("C:/path/to/custom_module")
import custom_module
print("It works")
```

I've got error like `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'`.
As I understand, the sys.path.append() works fine, but setting `os.environ["PATH"]` does not give desired result. The `some_module` is literally some module that is imported either by the `custom_module` or some others module that is in using.

I've played with slashes and backslashes in the paths, put the modifier `r` before string beginning, and also tried different cases for the `PATH` key (like `path`, `Path`).

Thus, I have two questions:

1. Why `os.environ["PATH"]` does not work (however when to `print()` it, it contains what I've set)
2. How is it possible to update the system paths in Python script (or in some other nice approach) to be able to work with custom modules?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `set PATH=…` destroys the _vital_ [`%PATH%`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) variable for current session…

Comment: Yes, it destroys... So what? :) Script works as expected! (well, it just do not require others paths that are replaced by new paths, it's fine for me now)